# I cannot access Phpadmin after modifying php.ini?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I tried to modify the php.ini files to detect errors. Once I did that I tried accessing **phpadmin** and the following error is shown.

Error
MySQL said: Documentation

## 1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.

I have since restored the php.ini file to its default settings/form and have restarted the servers through MAMP, But I still cannot access phpadmin.

Comment: Check the values in PHPadmin's config page.

Comment: you modified php.ini, ran into a problem, then put it back and problem persists.  what does that tell you?  *the access issue isn't related to the php.ini settings and probably never was.*  apparently something else changed around the same time.

Comment: I was able to access phpadmin before I modified some settings. Is it possible to have different mysql versions running on your computer?